# Java | MinecraftForge Error while runnig Client

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I have a problem with starting the minecraft client when I click Gradle> Tasks> fg_runs> runClient.

I get this error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ': runClient'.
> Process 'command' C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jdk1.8.0_291 \ bin \ java.exe '' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

and i don't know how to fix it.

Here is the entire log record: [Log Record](https://pastebin.com/8BCFZ91d)

Comment: "Invalid modId found in file F:\Mod\build\resources\main - JKMod does not match the standard: ^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]{1,63}$" seems relevant. Please make an effort to make questions self-contained in the future. Don't link to external resources, if the log is too big to paste into the question, try to figure out what part is relevant and paste only that. For example here there was a big stack trace in the log which is often the most relevant part.

Answer (score 0):

Your modid has to be lowercase, so find all the places you defined your modid and change it from JKMod to jkmod or any other modid that's completely lowercase.